# Is $f(x) = \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2\log(n)}$ a $C^1$ function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, trigonometry, fourier-series

Let $f$ be defined on the real line by
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2\log(n)}$$
Is $f$ a $C^1$ function?

I manage to prove that it is $C^1$ on $\mathbb R \setminus 2\pi \mathbb Z$ using Abel's summation technique.

I manage to prove that it is differentiable in $0$ (or at multiples of 2$\pi$) by showing that $\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} \to_{x \to 0} 0$.

However, what about the continuity of $f'$ at point $0$?

Answer (score 1):

The given series and the series of derivative $-\sum\frac {\sin (nx)} {n \log n}$ are both uniformly convergent. For uniform convergence of the later see the section '(C) and (S) series' in Fourier Series by Edwards. (Theorem 7.2.2 Partb (1), p. 112). The uniform convergence of these two series implies that your function does belong to $C^{1}$.

Comment: That works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint: your series is uniformly converged. For derivative series works [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)

Comment: not the series of the derivatives...

Comment: On any segment $[\varepsilon, 2\pi - \varepsilon]$ it is uniformly convergence, but you speaking about $0$-s neigbourhood?

Comment: that's the point...

Comment: @Aristodog The series of derivatives is also uniformly convergent but that is not obvious. See may answer below.

Comment: Here works Dirichlet's test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test